# Azure DevOps REST API Error: You are not authorized to create a subscription

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) documentation I try to make a user following a work item but I receive the following error:

```js
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "You are not authorized to create a subscription.",
    "typeName": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

The user which tries to create the subscription is an Admin of the project. Both users have access level Basic on organization level. The request uses Basic Auth with PAT with Full Access privileges. The same request succеeds in a different (test) organization but I don't see where is the difference between.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users want to set up Global notification, you need to make sure they are members of the Project Collection Administrators group of the organization.

I tested it in the UI, if the user is a project admin but not a member of the PCA group, then he has no permission to perform the operation.

[image]

Comment: I tested it as well, the same results here. The reason seems to be the lack of PCA membership. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing detail on your user role & licensing, those are usually the first two things to check in cases like these.

Since you're a Project Administrator and have at least a Basic license, I'd recommend checking two things:

1. If you're using the same PAT when issuing both calls between organizations, make sure that you've chosen "All accessible organizations" when configuring your PAT:
   [image: Azure DevOps - PAT Configuration]
2. Within your project, head to **Project Settings > Service Connections > Security**, verify that the user you're attempting to create a service connection with has access. If they don't, add them to the **Endpoint Administrators** group.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but neither of those solved the issue.

Comment: On the first point: it is a good idea to check the scope but if it is not for the target organisation you receive just Unauthorized 401 with no body. Anyway now my token has rights for all organizations it belongs to.
On the second point: My admin user has full rights to the project service connections along with the Security tab.
One thing more. My goal is to subscribe the regular user to receive emails on work item changes(make him/her following), using the admin account I have.
Thank you, any other inputs are welcome.

Comment: Is your user a Project Collection Administrator? Or, a Project Administrator for a single project?

Comment: Hi, it is just a Project Administrator for the prod organization and Project Collection Administrator for my test one. It look as a difference. Do you mean that I will need admin privileges on organization level in order to achieve this?